# Adding Paragraph / Lines to `info` in Tile (UI5) - Javascript View

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a problem with my Tiles. You can see the "..." in the info text for my Tile "Ui Elemente".

[image: Tiles in UI5]

How can I add a string in this info text above 2 Lines? `\n` doesn't work.

This is my Javascript code for a Tile. I declare all Tiles in a JSONModel.

```
{
    "Tile": {
        id: "idModelTile6",
        title: "Ui Elemente",
        info: "\n Weitere Ui Elemente",
        icon:"sap-icon://future",
        type: sap.m.StandardTileType.None
        //activeIcon:"switch-classes",
        //number:1,
        //numberUnit: "positions"
    },
},
```

Comment: you tried to just add an \ and press enter?

Comment: doesnt work :( . In Chrome i get more Lines in an developed App or in Simulator not :(

Answer (score 1):

Make your own CustomTile and add as many text lines as you like.